# amazon S3 privacy for Paperclip uploaded data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using Amazon S3 as hosting service for my `user` images uploaded with Paperclip.

Though i am struggling to understand how private those documents are.

I am not really bothered with my `user` images as they are designed to be shown on public profiles. Though in the future some PDF files will be dedicated to specific `users` and should only be viewed by these very `users`

Off course, my application will return the file that a user is entitled to see, though when looking at the HTTP addresses of the images and tweak them, some other images are delivered :

```
http://mywebsitename.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/photographephotos/images/000/000/013/big/CopyrightMM.JPG?1492617xxx
```

for example in the above address, when I change the number "13" to another figure I can see a different image...

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but it seems there is no unique token added to the image address, like a temporary session at Amazon S3 that would allow a single user to see this image for a short amount of time... unless the page is reloaded, and another token is attached to my image...

Regarding setup, I have created an IAM user and granted full access to the application bucket then setup Paperclip with the S3 credentials attached to that IAM user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model use:

```
 has_attached_file :file, s3_permissions: :private
```

And to retrieve the file URL use:

```
@model.file.expiring_url(10)
```

Comment: Pretty awesome thanks. by typing your fist line of code I ended on this Paperclip git page: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Restricting-Access-to-Objects-Stored-on-Amazon-S3 pretty cool